# Using Cakephp tests in production

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.3

I have a test suite for my cakephp web app using the cakephp phpunit wrapper provided in 2.x. I would love to merge my test suite into production and be able to test periodically in production via a test database. My issue is as followed:

CakePHP uses a file called test.php to run the test suite and index.php to run the site. I want to lock access to my test suite behind our administrative login, because I don't want anyone to be able to run my test suite on our site just by navigating to `www.myapp.com/test.php`

I cannot find any information about how to do this. Its possible that no one is doing this because this is a bad strategy that I have propose. If that is the case, could someone please direct me to a better cakephp testing strategy. Sorry, I'm new to building tests.

Thank you to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the web test suite but use the command line instead. See ["Running tests from the command line](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#run-tests-from-command-line)".

```
cake test
```

Also running tests on a production system might not be a good idea either as it can put some load on the server and the site might respond very slow while the tests run.

If you run the tests via command line you can use the command "[nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)" and set how much CPU load the command you're going to execute is allowed to cause.

Answer (score 0):

Here we set up a server that we run right next to production called development. These two servers are exact matches (I hope...) and we run our test suite from there. I still run them through the browser, but I agree that the command line works as describe by @burzum. Testing on live is a bad idea. It could mess things up and is not worth the risk for us.